# question about complex values in java

Tags: java, math, complex-numbers

We know that the general form of complex numbers is like this:
  `z=a+i*b`, where i is `sqrt(-1)`.

I have a question about how to express this in Java ?

Comment: Google found dozens of implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library provides anything you would need with complex numbers:
http://commons.apache.org/math/

Example:
http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/complex.html